# Determining the position of sub-string in list of strings

Tags: python, string, sorting, python-2.7

I have a list of words (strings), say:

```
word_lst = ['This','is','a','great','programming','language']
```

And a second list with sub-strings, say:

```
subs_lst= ['This is', 'language', 'a great']
```

And let's suppose each sub-string in subs_lst appears only one time in word_lst. (sub-strings can be of any length)

I want an easy way to find the hierarchical position of the sub-strings in the word_lst.
So what I want is to order subs_lst according to they appearance in word_lst.
In the previous example, the output would be:

```
out = ['This is', 'a great', language]
```

Does anyone know an easy way to do this?

Comment: Will the sub-strings in `subs_lst` always be made up of consecutive elements in `word_list`? Meaning, given your example `word_lst`, could `"This language"` be in `subs_lst`?

Comment: Yes. only consecutive elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intermediate step seems unneeded to me. Why not just make the word list a single string and find the substrings in that?

```
 sorted(subs_lst, key = lambda x : ' '.join(word_lst).index(x))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a faster way to do this, but this works, at least:

```
word_lst = ['This','is','a','great','programming','language']
subs_lst= ['This is', 'language', 'a great']
substr_lst = [' '.join(word_lst[i:j]) for i in range(len(word_lst)) for j in range(i+1, len(word_lst)+1)]
sorted_subs_list = sorted(subs_lst, key=lambda x:substr_lst.index(x))
print sorted_subs_list
```

Output:

```
['This is', 'a great', 'language']
```

The idea is to build a list of every substring in `word_lst`, ordered so that all the entries that start with "This" come first, followed by all the entries starting with "is", etc.. We store that in `substr_lst`.

```
>>> print substr_lst
['This', 'This is', 'This is a', 'This is a great', 'This is a great programming', 'This is a great programming language', 'is', 'is a', 'is a great', 'is a great programming', 'is a great programming language', 'a', 'a great', 'a great programming', 'a great programming language', 'great', 'great programming', 'great programming language', 'programming', 'programming language', 'language']
```

Once we have that list, we sort subs_list, using the index of each entry in `substr_list` as the key to sort by:

```
>>> substr_lst.index("This is")
1
>>> substr_lst.index("language")
20
>>> substr_lst.index("a great")
12
```

Comment: +1 for comprehension-fu (and no-regex answer in regex question!) :)